# making a custom back button in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I am new to iphone so I have a very simple question. I am using a storyboard in `xcode 4.2`. I have multiple screens with about buttion in each `viewController`.

Now I have created segues ofc. Each about button i have linked with about `viewController`. However I am not using a `navigation controller`.

I have custom made a back button. How can i go back to the screen which brought me on the about section.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are modally presenting the new view controllers they can be dismissed using the following.

```
-(IBAction)myCloseAction:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are not using navigation controller, u need to manually do the pushing and popping viewcontroller. When u change the viewcontroller, store previous viewcontroller reference in the new viewcontroller and when back button is pressed goto the previously stored viewcontroller.